# Save Entity without Relationship in Swift Core Data

Tags: swift, database, core-data, entity-relationship

I'm working an a simple soccer application right now. This is how my (simplified) Core Data model looks like:

**Game entity:**

[image: Game entity]

**Team entity:**

[image: Team entity]

*Generally: I know that the inverse relationships are missing. This has nothing to do with my question but I somebody knows hat to do these: Please tell me ;)*

**EXAMPLE SCENARIO:**

I create a new Game with date (not important) and set *home* to a team with the name "Team A" and *away*  to a team with the name "Team B". Works fine.

When I edit the name of "Team A", the name of the home team of the games changes, too. Of course it does, it's a relationship.

But this is not what I want it do do because once I've created a game, it shouldn't change the data.

I thought of moving the home and away data to a attribute of the Game entity but I can't set the type to Team.

**MY QUESTION:**

Is it possible to create a kind of copy of a Team object and save it to the Game object? It should be independent from the Team object in the database and represent a "static copy".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep historical data, you will need to either create a new snapshot entity (`GameTeam` or something similar) or copy all the "static" values across to new fields in the `Team` entity.